# Material UI Drawer set background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How to simply set the background color of Material UI `Drawer`?
tried this, but doesn't work

```
<Drawer 
  style={listStyle3}
  open={this.state.menuOpened}
  docked={false}
  onRequestChange={(menuOpened) => this.setState({menuOpened})}
/>

const listStyle3 = {
  background: '#fafa00',
  backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edit: (May-21) - Material UI V4.11.1**
This can be done differently in version 4.11.1 and functional components.
There's no need to use an HoC anymore. Here's how it's done:
You should use the [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles) helper to create the hook with a definitions of the classes and use the hook to pull them out.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  list: {
    width: 250
  },
  fullList: {
    width: "auto"
  },
  paper: {
    background: "blue"
  }
});

const DrawerWrapper = () => {
 const classes = useStyles();
  return (
     <Drawer
        classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      >
        <div
          tabIndex={0}
          role="button"
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
          classes={{ root: classes.root }}
        >
          {sideList}
        </div>
      </Drawer>
    )
}
```

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jmyb1?file=/demo.js:2905-3298)

---

**Edit: (Jan-19) - Material UI V3.8.3**
As for the latest version asked, the way to configure the `backgroundColor` would be by overriding the classes.
Based on material-ui documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes), and the css api for drawer [here](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/#css-api) - This can be done by creating an object in the form of:

```
const styles = {
  paper: {
    background: "blue"
  }
}
```

and passing it to the Drawer component:

```
 <Drawer
      classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
      open={this.state.left}
      onClose={this.toggleDrawer("left", false)}
    >
```

A working example can be seen in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q56r5ol89) codesandbox.
Don't forget to wrap your component with material-ui's `withStyles` HoC as mentioned [here](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#higher-order-component-api)

---

Based on the props you used I have the reason to think that you're using a version which is lower than `v1.3.1` (the last stable version) but for the next questions you'll ask, I recommend writing the version you're using.

For version lower than `V1`, you can change the `containerStyle` prop like this:

`<Drawer open={true} containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>`

Comment: sometimes style, sometimes containerStyle, so confusing. It works, Thank you!

Comment: Matan Bobi . What are the options for latest Verstion?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I was using backgroundColor but had to change it to just background

Comment: Finally, something worked. The css is made so complex. I'm in the process of migrating from 0.x to 3.x and scratching my head over this new way of applying css.

Comment: It seems that this solution is not working in Material UI **4.0.0**

Comment: In Material UI 4.0.0 it's no working this code `background: "blue"` unless you define a **gradient as a background**

Comment: @JuanSalvador, Thanks for the input. I tested it with the sandbox and version `4.0.1` and looks like it works as supposed to. Am I missing something?

Comment: This can still be done but as of 4.11.0, drawer style is referred to as drawerPaper not paper.

Answer (score 45):

In **Material UI v5**, you can use the `sx` prop to style Material UI components:

```
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      color: "red",
    }
  }}
```

Or use `styleOverrides` to define the custom styles in `createTheme`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      styleOverrides: {
        paper: {
          backgroundColor: "pink",
          color: "red",
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Wooh that worked for me ! Thanks

Comment: The key point of explanation missing here is that the Drawer component outputs a container that has both the overlay (darkened semi-transparent div that covers the entire screen) and the actual menu (Paper component menu that slides out). By adding a background color directly to the Drawer, you're affecting the **container**, so that would cover the entire screen. What you want to target is the actual menu (or Paper) component. And of course, as you see in the example, that's done through the attribute `PaperProps`.

Answer (score 7):

**Material UI V4.3.2**
As in this version you can change the backgroundColor by making use of makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles' as shown below:

```
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    background: 'black',
    color: 'white'
  }
});

const SideDrawer = props => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <Drawer
      anchor="right"
      open={props.drawerOpen}
      onClose={() => props.toggleDrawer(false)}
      classes={{ paper: styles.paper }}
    >
      Items
    </Drawer>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawer doesn't accept style props. Use *classes* instead

See [Drawer API](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's looking for how to do this conditionally for dark/light mode, you can make 2 separate classes and use a conditional to use the right one in the component. Here's an example of how to modify [@Yirenkyi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57533576/12309608) do achieve this:

```
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paperLight: {
    background: 'white',
    color: 'black'
  },
  paperDark: {
    background: 'black',
    color: 'white'
  }
});

const SideDrawer = props => {
  
  const userPrefersDarkMode = true; //here's your condition

  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <Drawer
      anchor="right"
      open={props.drawerOpen}
      onClose={() => props.toggleDrawer(false)}
      classes={{ paper: userPrefersDarkMode ? styles.paperDark : styles.paperLight }}
    >
      Items
    </Drawer>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```